# Unable to install postgreSQL 9.6 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, postgresql

It worked hundred times in my ci/cd pipeline, but suddenly stopped to work and idk what could I broke.

According to [this](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/postgresql?dist=focal-pgdg) and/or [this](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-postgresql-9-6-on-ubuntu-20-04/), I do:

```
lsb_release -cs # just for debug
focal

echo "deb https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add -
```

just for debug:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list 
deb https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg main
```

then `apt-get update`:

```
Get:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease [1811 B]
Get:2 https://apt.corretto.aws stable InRelease [10.7 kB]
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease [23.8 kB]
Get:4 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease [17.1 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
Get:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages [1092 B]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:10 https://apt.corretto.aws stable/main amd64 Packages [6233 B]
Get:11 https://apt.corretto.aws stable/main i386 Packages [2115 B]
Get:12 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [12.1 kB]
Get:13 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable/main i386 Packages [10.5 kB]
Get:14 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable/main amd64 Packages [10.5 kB]
Get:15 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable/main all Packages [10.5 kB]
Get:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [3165 B]
Get:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [3170 B]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages [5999 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages [11.3 MB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages [177 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [1275 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 Packages [33.4 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [930 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal/partner amd64 Packages [801 B]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted i386 Packages [10.1 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse i386 Packages [88.9 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [632 kB]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1081 kB]
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [9320 B]
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [794 kB]
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages [23.5 kB]
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [1582 kB]
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [681 kB]
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [33.3 kB]
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main i386 Packages [2671 B]
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages [6310 B]
Get:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 Packages [2668 B]
Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe i386 Packages [5084 B]
Get:39 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages [580 kB]
Ign:40 https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease
Get:41 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted i386 Packages [22.1 kB]
Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [30.1 kB]
Get:43 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse i386 Packages [8172 B]
Get:44 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages [358 kB]
Get:45 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [1133 kB]
Get:46 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [794 kB]
Get:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe i386 Packages [628 kB]
Err:48 https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg Release
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses expired certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 147.75.85.69 443]

Reading package lists...
E: The repository 'https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg Release' does not have a Release file.
```

As far as I can see the ssl cert for `https://apt.postgresql.org` is valid at this moment. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Im going to bet 200 quatloos that this is part of [the recent Let’s Encrypt root certificate expiration](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/). You may want to remove the repo from the update process for a week or so until everyone has caught up on the updates 

Comment: @matigo is there any way to manually update it on Ubuntu?